# OpenAI PHP embedding documentation Q&A wrong similarity response

Tags: php, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I followed the guide from this website: *[Using OpenAI to create a Q&A in Laravel/PHP with embedding](https://www.guywarner.dev/using-openai-to-create-a-qa-in-laravelphp-with-embedding)*

I just remade it in PHP.

But now it seems I have a logical error.

Firstly, I get the embeddings for the source document:

```
<?php
    include('vendor/autoload.php');

    $client = OpenAI::client('API');

    /* Get file */
    $filename = 'sample-chatgpt-file.txt';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($filename);

    // Get data split in 2000 characters because of OpenAI
    $split = openai_str_split($file_contents);

    // Get embedding from OpenAI
    $return = getInputs($split);

    // Save embedding of entry file so we can work with it later
    $file = 'embed.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, serialize($return));
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $retrieved_data = unserialize($contents);

    // Display what we got
    print_r($retrieved_data);

    // Function for embedding creation
    function getInputs($prompts)
    {
        $client = OpenAI::client('API');

        return $client->embeddings()->create([
            'model' => 'text-embedding-ada-002',
            'input' => $prompts,
        ]);
    }

    // Function for splitting entry file
    function openai_str_split($text) {
        $max_length = 1996;

        $sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $text);

        $chunks = array();
        $chunk = '';

        foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
            $sentence_length = strlen($sentence);

            if (strlen($chunk) + $sentence_length > $max_length) {
                $chunks[] = $chunk;
                $chunk = '';
            }

            $chunk .= $sentence . ' ';
        }

        if (!empty($chunk)) {
            $chunks[] = $chunk;
        }

        return $chunks;
    }
```

Then I get embedding for the question and try to get an answer from OpenAI for the source document and question:

```
<?php
    include('vendor/autoload.php');

    $client = OpenAI::client('API');

    // Entry file
    $VhodniFile = 'sample-chatgpt-file.txt';
    $prompts = file_get_contents($VhodniFile);

    // Entry file embedding
    $file = 'embed.txt';
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $inputs = unserialize($contents);

    // Question
    $userQuestion = 'How does closing of source items work?';

    // Get embedding for question
    $question = $client->embeddings()->create([
                'model' => 'text-embedding-ada-002',
                'input' => $userQuestion,
            ]);

    // Get answer
    $answer = getAnswer($prompts, $inputs, $question);

    //print_r($answer);

    // Display match
    print_r("The ada match: " . $prompts[$answer['index']]);

    // Prompt to send to OpenAI
    $davinci = "Rewrite the question and give the answer with an example in PHP from the context
            Context: {$prompts[$answer['index']]}
            Question: {$userQuestion}
            Answer:";
    //print_r($davinci);

    // Send prompt to GPT-3 DaVinci
    $result = $client->completions()->create([
                  'model' => 'text-davinci-003',
                  'prompt' => $davinci,
                  'temperature' => 0.5,
                  'max_tokens' => 1000,
              ]);

    print_r($result);

    // Result output
    print("Naredi berljivo: {$result['choices'][0]['text']}");

    function getAnswer($prompts, $inputs, $question)
    {
        // Loops through all the inputs and compare on a cosine similarity to the question and output the correct answer
        $results = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputs->embeddings); $i++) {
            $similarity = cosineSimilarity($inputs->embeddings[$i]->embedding, $question->embeddings[0]->embedding);
            // Store the similarity and index in an array and sort by the similarity
            $results[] = [
                'similarity' => $similarity,
                'index' => $i,
                'input' => $prompts[$i],
            ];
        }
        usort($results, function ($a, $b) {
            return $a['similarity'] <=> $b['similarity'];
        });

        return end($results);
    }

    function cosineSimilarity($u, $v)
    {
        $dotProduct = 0;
        $uLength = 0;
        $vLength = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($u); $i++) {
            $dotProduct += $u[$i] * $v[$i];
            $uLength += $u[$i] * $u[$i];
            $vLength += $v[$i] * $v[$i];
        }
        $uLength = sqrt($uLength);
        $vLength = sqrt($vLength);
        return $dotProduct / ($uLength * $vLength);
    }
```

The problem is the function getAnswer only returns the letter 'a' in this case and obviously because of that the answer I get from OpenAI is plain wrong and not correct.

I pasted the code for both files, because I don’t know if the embeddings are off or is something else not working correctly.

Comment: If `getAnswer` would only return "a", then `$answer['index']` would throw an error. But my guess is that the problem is `$prompts` being a string and not an array.

Comment: @gre_gor so do you think i have to pas the $prompts entry file as an array just like i'm doing with the embedding file? So, using the function function openai_str_split($text)?

Comment: Sine `$prompts[$i]` gives you individual characters, yes.